# Securing Firebase Integration: How to Safeguard 3rd Party Firebase Instance for Authentication Without Data Leakage and Control Concerns?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, authentication

I have successfully integrated a 3rd party Firebase instance for authentication in my application, alongside my existing Firebase instance for analytics and remote config. However, I'm concerned about potential data leakage and whether the 3rd party Firebase instance could gain any control over my application beyond providing authentication services.

1. What measures can I take to ensure the 3rd party Firebase instance is securely locked down, preventing inadvertent data leakage from my app to the 3rd party?
2. Additionally, what level of control does the 3rd party Firebase instance have over my application, especially in terms of potential impacts on user privacy and data security?

Any insights or best practices to address these concerns would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!